# In Jmeter how to pass Date as String/text

Tags: date, jmeter

I need to pass a date (12/12/2016) as a Text parameter to a Post request.
It picks %2f instead of '/'. how do i pass this as string with date having slash.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to send date value as Text/string in parameters tab. whether I select/unselect `Encode?` parameter, sending by encoding the date value.

Keeping the value in `Body Data` section worked for me.

So, try by moving all the Post data into `Body Data` section instead of `Parameters` section.

[image]

Comment: I have more than 20 paremeters. What format should i use if it has to be transformed to Body data.?

Comment: use `key1=value1&key2=value2` (seperated by `&`). reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request

Comment: This Worked. Thanks!